# IllegalArgumentException: Only private key data is currently supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, oauth-2.0, private-key

I get this error by this method:

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {

    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("publickey.txt");
    String publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    converter.setSigningKey(publicKey);
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
}
```

Anyone who has a solution for this error?

Comment: ... because you need a private key to sign?

Comment: As signing key and as verifierkey?

Comment: Signature is created using a private key, verified a public key. So signing key should be a private key (to be used signing a token), verifier should be a public key exposed for resource servers to validate the signature, (at least as javadoc claims)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you do not need to specify the verifier key separately, and if you do it must match the signing key
<-- then I get this error